# next-redux-wrapper and mixing client & server states. Should it raise "Text content does not match server-rendered HTML" error?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, next-redux-wrapper

In next.js the SSR-rendered page and the client-hydrated page should match, otherwise, we gonna get a content mismatch alert during the hydration. But using next-redux-wrapper we amend the redux client state on HYDRATE action mixing together client and server states. At first sight looks like it violates this rule and should raise the error. Or not?